# php Countdown timer based on file modified time

Tags: php, timer

I have a file on our server that gets overwritten every 10 minutes with an updated file called AgentReport.html

I have a webpage that uses an iframe to display the AgentReport.html with a meta refresh set to 60 seconds.

I am trying to create a basic php countdown timer to display how long until the next update using filemtime to grab the minutes of the last modified date for AgentReport.html.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$nextUpdate = date ("i", filemtime("AgentReport.html")) + 10;
$currtime = date ("i");
$remaining = ($nextUpdate - $currtime - 1);
if ($remaining >= 60) {
    $remaining = ($remaining - 60) . "minutes";
}
else if ($remaining <= 1) {
    $remaining = "a minute";
}
else $remaining = $remaining . " minutes";
echo "Next update in about " . $remaining;

?>
```

This is sloppy but almost works.. but I am getting confused.  I am having a hard time navigating the turn of an hour (report seems to hit the server at say 10:52) and handling the last minute so it displays properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is it doing when it hits those problem times?

Comment: Let's say the file updates at 10:52.  At 11:01, the time remaining is 61 minutes.

Then when it gets down to where $remaining = 1, it would say 1 minute remaining... but when $remaining = 0 (could be 59 seconds left), I still technically have about a minute remaining...

Comment: you could add a +1 to cover that.

Comment: I guess that's where I am getting confused... where to add or subtract this 1 so it will make sense.. and still work with the top of the hour conversion.

Comment: you already have an if statement for <1 minute.  If you know that is inaccurate, put the calculation in there along with the text change.  You can also do another calculation on the other end, since you know it won't be over 60 minutes;  make sure that the cap is 60, and subtract any time in between the last update and the end of the hour

Comment: note:  I know this might create some overly sloppy code, so doing it the way Jurgis suggested below might be cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$nextUpdate = filemtime("AgentReport.html") + 10*60;
$currTime   = time();
$min        = (int)(($nextUpdate-$currTime)/60);
echo 'Next update in about '.($min <= 1 ? 'a minute' : $min.' minutes');
?>
```

Comment: This is definitely a cleaner way to do it.  But when file updates at 10:55 and the current time is 11:02, will it say there is 3 minutes left or 63 minutes left?  Also, it will say "about a minute" for the last two minutes of the cycle.. rather than the last minute.

Comment: It will say about a minute for two minutes. But that is correct as it will be less than 2 minutes.

Comment: @J--: If you wanted it to say `about a minute` when actually only under a minute just add one minute to `$min` (eg. `$min = $min + 1; `). This is what I would probably recommend, since it seems that you'd be losing a minute off the count from the very start. It can go either way, since the `about` value can be `+` or `-` the actual value, it's really just personal preference. Good solution here nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I had in mind.  Since the page refreshes every minute regardless of the updated time, I would like it to show 10 mins on the first new report refresh and go down a minute each refresh. So I tried just adding 11 minutes originally instead of just 10.  So the minutes remaining starts at 10.  Then just change the <=1 to <1 ..not able to test at the moment but I think that would do it.